# What will be mode of operation for BJT in figure?

Tags: transistors, bjt

[image]

The value of Vbe active is .7V. Also give reason.

Comment: smoke and fire with 2.5V between B and E

Comment: The standard definition of a BJT spec for saturation is Vce(sat) @ Ic=2.5mA when Ic/Ib =10 with Ib limited by (Voh-Vbe)/Rb which includes driver output resistance and some series Rb for the applied Voh. However the assumption is wrong for this input current when Ib=250uA if designed this way as Vbe<=0.6V @ < 1mA base current when series R is included. otherwise Vbe increases and overheats from Vbe*Ibe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the BJT will be in saturation, it might over-heat and burn in practice. Also this circuit will definitely not be amplifying anything as its in saturation and proper coupling doesnt exist b/w microphone and BJT.
The reason should be obvious, the Vbe on = .7V and Ic=Is*e^(-Vbe/Vt)$ where Vt=26mV. Thus Ic rises exponentially with increase in Vbe and results in saturation of the BJT.